# bold text within **text** marks php

Tags: php

I'm working in this function that colors an username in case it exists `@username` within an string.

**PHP**

```
$string="this **text** contains a second **content**"
```

I want to bold the text contained within **text**

I tried but nothing

```
 function bold_word($string) {
   return preg_replace('/(\**+)/', "<b>$1</b>", $string);
    }
```

Comment: ok. It was a typo

Comment: thank you for marking. I found the answer there `preg_replace('#\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}#', '<b>$1</b>', $tring);`